# wp-simple web service POST method

Tags: wordpress, web-services, plugins

I am using wp-simple webservice plugin for REST API.
most of the examples shown with GET method.

How i can get response for a  POST method using wp-simple-webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Check This Link,it's a simple tutorial for WP web services(get and post method) - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-creating-updating-and-deleting-data--cms-24883

Comment: Is there any way to customize the wp-simple webservice plugin for post method?